# cannot install kubuntu-desktop

Tags: kubuntu

Tried installing 'kubuntu-desktop' from synaptic manager. But, failed showing the following error-

"**Could not mark all packages for installation or upgrade**
The following packages have unresolvable dependencies. Make sure all required repositories are added and enabled in preferences.

```
kubuntu-desktop:<br>
 Depends: ark but it is not going to be installed<br>
 Depends: dolphin but it is not going to be installed<br>
 Depends: kde-window-manager<br>
 Depends: kde-workspace-bin but it is not going to be installed<br>
 Depends: kdemultimedia-kio-plugins but it is not going to be installed<br>
 Depends: kdepasswd but it is not going to be installed<br>
 Depends: kdm but it is not going to be installed<br>
 Depends: khelpcenter4 but it is not going to be installed<br>
 Depends: klipper but it is not going to be installed<br>
 Depends: kmix but it is not going to be installed<br>
 Depends: konsole but it is not going to be installed<br>
 Depends: ksnapshot but it is not going to be installed<br>
 Depends: ksysguard but it is not going to be installed<br>
 Depends: language-selector-kde but it is not going to be installed<br>
 Depends: okular but it is not going to be installed<br>
 Depends: plasma-desktop but it is not going to be installed<br>
 Depends: plasma-netbook but it is not going to be installed<br>
 Depends: software-properties-kde but it is not going to be installed<br>
 Depends: systemsettings but it is not going to be installed<br>
 Recommends: akregator but it is not going to be installed<br>
 Recommends: amarok but it is not going to be installed<br>
 Recommends: apport-kde but it is not going to be installed<br>
 Recommends: apturl-kde but it is not going to be installed....
```

.........."

My '/etc/apt/sources.list' has the following-

'

```
# See 'http://help.ubuntu.com/community/UpgradeNotes' for how to upgrade to<br>
'# newer versions of the distribution.<br>
'deb cdrom:[Ubuntu 12.04.1 LTS _Precise Pangolin_ - Release amd64 (20120823.1)]/ 'dists/precise/main/binary-i386/<br>
'# deb cdrom:[Ubuntu 12.04.1 LTS _Precise Pangolin_ - Release amd64 (20120823.1)]/ 'dists/precise/restricted/binary-i386/<br>
'# deb cdrom:[Ubuntu 12.04.1 LTS _Precise Pangolin_ - Release amd64 (20120823.1)]/ 'precise main restricted<br>
'deb 'http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu precise main restricted multiverse<br>

'## Major bug fix updates produced after the final release of the<br>
'## distribution.<br>

'## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu<br>
'## team. Also, please note that software in universe WILL NOT receive any<br>
'## review or updates from the Ubuntu security team.<br>
'deb 'http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu precise universe<br>

'## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu<br>
'## team, and may not be under a free licence. Please satisfy yourself as to<br>
'## your rights to use the software. Also, please note that software in<br>
'## multiverse WILL NOT receive any review or updates from the Ubuntu<br>
'## security team.<br>

'## N.B. software from this repository may not have been tested as<br>
'## extensively as that contained in the main release, although it includes<br>
'## newer versions of some applications which may provide useful features.<br>
'## Also, please note that software in backports WILL NOT receive any review<br>
'## or updates from the Ubuntu security team.<br>

'deb 'http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu precise-security main restricted multiverse<br>
'deb 'http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu precise-security universe<br>

'## Uncomment the following two lines to add software from Canonical's<br>
'## 'partner' repository.<br>
'## This software is not part of Ubuntu, but is offered by Canonical and the<br>
'## respective vendors as a service to Ubuntu users.<br>
'deb 'http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu oneiric partner<br>
'# deb-src 'http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu oneiric partner<br>

'## This software is not part of Ubuntu, but is offered by third-party<br>
'## developers who want to ship their latest software.<br>
'# deb 'http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu precise main<br>
'# deb-src 'http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu precise main
```

Kindly give a solution...

Answer (score 2):

probably the problem is that you're missing the `precise-updates` repository, therefore apt/synaptic can't find the right dependencies for kubuntu-desktop

try adding

```
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu precise-updates main restricted universe multiverse
```

to your `sources.list`, then `sudo apt-get update`, then try installing kubuntu-desktop again

as an off-topic: you probably also want to change the partner line from `oneiric` to `precise`